# How can I prevent addition of Strings in URL in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I created a dynamic menu that is accessible to both public and registered users.
The problem is that I have this:

```
{pages.length > 0 ? (
  pages.map(page => (
    <li key={page._id} className="nav-item">
      {page._id ? (
        <Link to={`pages/${page._id}`} className="nav-link">{page.title}</Link>
      ) : (
          <Link to={`pages/${page._id}`} className="nav-link">Hola 2</Link>
        )}
    </li>
  ))
) : (
    <li className="nav-item">
      <a className="nav-link" href="#!">No Pages Found</a>
    </li>
  )}
```

Now when I'm in the homepage and a click a URL, the links works great:

```
localhost:3000/pages/5d2ea3a1ef0ba93f9cd1b980
```

Once I'm inside an URL, I try to click a different link and suddenly it now behaves like this:

```
localhost:3000/pages/pages/5d2ea3a1ef0ba93f9cd1b980
```

and so on:

```
localhost:3000/pages/pages/pages/5d2ea3a1ef0ba93f9cd1b980
```

Does anyone has an idea why is this happening?

Comment: try with ```<Link to={`/pages/${page._id}`} className="nav-link">Hola 2</Link>```

Comment: I can not believe it was so easy to solve, thank you!. I'm going to mark your comment as useful as you did not publish an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to={/pages/${page._id}}` instead of `to={pages/${page._id}}`. If the link doesn't start with a `/`, it is treated as relative to current url.